# Cycle 2.8 Cuda error at cuCtxCreate: Illegal Address

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

Am trying to bake a simple object, it has one material:

[image]

And a Texture node with the right image selected:
[image]

no idea though why the Texture slot when i select the object is always empty and shows nothing:
[image]

Now if i bake that for the first time it works like it should:
[image]

Now i don't touch anything, keep the same object selected, and hit Bake again, 
That baked texture is all of a sudden empty, the baking stop after 1% and i get this message:

**Baking map saved to internal image. save it externally or pack it**

And the worst part is that the viewport Render mode stop rendering, its all gray

[image]

And if i just press F12 to render the whole scene, i get this error:

**Cuda error at cuCtxCreate: Illegal Address**

Any help please ?

Thanks!

PS:
If i restart Blender 2.8 , the same thing happens again, i can render as much as i want, but if i do a texture Bake, the first time it works, and after that this problem happens all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this seems like its a known bug that has already been reported
https://developer.blender.org/T59238

Comment: I was getting the same message in Cycles Cuda error at cuCtxCreate: Illegal Address. I had a Denoise filter in Compositing. I removed it, came out of Blender, got back in and put back the Denoise Filter - error fixed. I had to close and open for the fix. If you don't have the Denoise filter on look at other nodes you set up mainly in Compositing window. I don't think it has anything to do with the texturing nodes. Anyway, it requires more digging here to find out exactly why is this happening.